# PHP error: “syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')'

Tags: php, syntax

In the following code:

```
if(OS == "XP"){
    if header('Location: XP.html');
exit();
}
```

It says the error is in line 3 (which is the "if header" line) but I'm just not seeing it. Is it really a syntax error, or is it something else.

Comment: "Is it really a syntax error" --- you don't trust php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issued an `if` statement. So Naturally, PHP looks to complete the statement. Hence why your getting the error stating an expected closing bracket.

Remove your if statement and your code should look like this:

```
if(OS == "XP"){
    header('Location: XP.html');
exit();
}
```

PHP error reporting isn't the best tool in the world. It alerts you to the rough place, but it's up to you to look for what should and shouldn't be near/on that line.

Answer (score 1):

Is `OS` a constant defined somewhere? If not, try this:

Try this:

```
if( $OS == "XP" )
{
    header( 'Location: XP.html' );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: OS is a constant defined in the main HTML document. It is a form that outputs different values to the php to redirect the user. Probably not the best way to do it, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

`if` should always be followed by a `(`

remove the `if` in line 2. I don't think its necessary

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. But I still don't redirect to XP.html Now its just a blank page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `if` on line two should not be there.

```
if(OS == "XP"){
    header('Location: XP.html');
    exit();
}
```